# Twitter with Backbone js

Tags: twitter, backbone.js

I'm trying to implement the Twitter(as simple as possible) with Backbone js.
 does anybody have idea about how the twitter model should be?

I thought it to be something like this.

```
var tweetModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    default:{           
        screenName  : 'ScName',
        tweets      : [],
        followers   : []     //These ppl shd see the tweets by him
    }
});
```

But here , to which thing view should be binded?
If we take tweet as a seperate collection also, how to notify about the tweets from the people you are following?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the twitter api return a json object? I'd just use that as the model.

Comment: can u giv me the sample of that Json model?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224839/unable-to-fetch-data-from-twitter-restful-api-using-backbone-js-collection

Comment: you'd want to use the json returned from twitter within a collection.  not a model